# How to get rid off table without double quotes at all for all operations?

Tags: oracle, nestjs, typeorm

How can I to remove double quotes from this select generated by typeorm

```
select * from "test"."table"
```

QueryFailedError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
at OracleQueryRunner.query (C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\src\driver\oracle\OracleQueryRunner.ts:274:19) {
query: 'SELECT "table"."id" AS "table_id" FROM "test"."table" "table"',
parameters: [],
driverError: [Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist] {
errorNum: 942,
offset: 74
},
errorNum: 942,
offset: 74
}

Comment: One option is to perform **find** (double quotes) / **replace** (with *nothing*) in any text editor. In TypeORM? No idea.

Comment: No idea if TypeORM lets you change the behaviour. You could change the code you're using to generate the query to have uppercase table/column names, including entity names - or, more correctly, matching the case of the names in `all_tables` and `all_tab_columns`. Then it won't matter if the names are quoted in the query. if the data dictionary shows the table name as `TEST` then you can query `test`, `Test`, `tEsT` (any case without quotes) *or* `"TEST"` to exactly match with quotes.

Comment: so how i created table and schema without quotes, the query throws an error that there is no such table, a query generated by typeorm

Comment: If you create the table without quotes, e.g. `create table test ...`, then it will be in the data dictionary as `TEST`. That's fine normally, but since TypeORM appears to always be adding the quotes to the generated query, your references there have to match the data dictionary exactly - so it generates it as `SELECT "TABLE"."ID" AS "TABLE_ID"....`. (Presumably these aren't your real names as `table` is a reserved words, and would have to be quoted if you really has a table called that...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have somehow created a table called "table" I would strongly recomend that you rename avoiding all reserved / key words.
One option is to add an underscore and or a number.
Table_1 is valid and will not need to be quoted etc.
Of course it's always better to use meaningful names.

Here is the syntax for renaming a table:

```
RENAME TABLE table-Name TO new-Table-Name
```

so you could try

```
RENAME TABLE "test"."table" TO test.table_1;
```